# Issue with chef solo - unable to find cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I've recently been attempting to use Chef to provision my local development environment, however I am unable to get Chef to recognize where cookbooks are located. I am wondering if anyone can help shed some light on what it is I am missing?

I have been running chef-solo from the folder where I have set everything up using the following command:

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb
```

This produces the following output:

> Starting Chef Client, version 12.4.1 Compiling Cookbooks...
>
> Running handlers: [2015-07-31T11:52:26+01:00] ERROR: Running exception
>   handlers Running handlers complete [2015-07-31T11:52:26+01:00] ERROR:
>   Exception handlers complete Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in
>   14.12488 seconds [2015-07-31T11:52:26+01:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/chef-stacktrace.out [2015-07-31T11:52:26+01:00] FATAL:
>   Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook sublime-text not found.
>   If you're loading sublime-text from another cookbook, ma ke sure you
>   configure the dependency in your metadata

I have however specified where to find the cookbooks in the solo.rb file, which looks as follows:

```
root = File.absolute_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

file_cache_path root
cookbook_path root + "/cookbooks"
json_attribs root + "/solo.json"
```

And the solo.json file looks as follows:

```
{
    "run_list": [
        "recipe[sublime-text::default]"
    ]
}
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Chef
  -- cookbooks
     -- sublime-text
  -- solo.json
  -- solo.rb
```

Is there something I am missing to specify the path to the cookbooks properly? Or even better, is this even the correct way to go about provisioning one machine using chef-solo?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use chef-client in local mode - I had problems with solo with cookbooks, too.

If you want to know, how to use chef-client, here is command:

```
  C:\opscode\chef\bin\chef-client --local -j run_list.json
```

I run this from directory with cookbooks:

```
 Script
   - run_list.json
   - cookbooks
      - windows-master
      - chef_handler
      - my_cookbook
```

Remember to run this script from "Script" directory.

Comment: what is the difference between chef-client in local and solo? whats the point of having solo even?